# как в beautifulsoup исключать строки?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, bs4

Вот код:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    doc = open(r'C:\Users\QuosX\Desktop\сообщения\messages0.html')  

    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "html.parser")

    message = soup.findAll ("div")
    text = soup.a.text
    print(text)
```

Выдает что-то наподобие такого:

```
</div></div>
</div><div class="item">
<div class="item__main"><div class="message" data-id="123123">
<div class="message__header">Вы, 1 мая 2020 в 13:54:55</div>
<div>НУЖНЫЙ ТЕКСТ</div>
</div></div>
</div><div class="item">
<div class="item__main"><div class="message" data-id="1231212">
<div class="message__header">Вы, 1 мая 2020 в 13:54:54</div>
<div>НУЖНЫЙ ТЕКСТ</div>
</div></div>
</div><div class="item">
```

Он спарсил все div-ы, но мне нужны только те, где есть НУЖНЫЙ ТЕКСТ, а остальные убрать, как это сделать?

Comment: Похоже, Что Это [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/339283)

Comment: Для исключения строк есть метод `extract`, но он навряд ли Вам поможет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете парсить только те `div`'ы, где есть необходимый текст. Для этого воспользуйтесь атрибутом `text`.

***Пример:***

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('index.html', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'lxml')

result = soup.findAll('div', text='НУЖНЫЙ ТЕКСТ')
print(result)
```

***stdout:***

```py
[<div>НУЖНЫЙ ТЕКСТ</div>, <div>НУЖНЫЙ ТЕКСТ</div>]
```

***index.html:***

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item__main">
    <div class="message" data-id="123123">
      <div class="message__header">Вы, 1 мая 2020 в 13:54:55</div>
      <div>НУЖНЫЙ ТЕКСТ</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item__main">
    <div class="message" data-id="1231212">
      <div class="message__header">Вы, 1 мая 2020 в 13:54:54</div>
      <div>НУЖНЫЙ ТЕКСТ</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```